# Linear curve to wave curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, transforms

I would like to create a shape/curve similar to the white line on the picture below. From linear curve to wave curve.

How can I create this one?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to work in wireframe view

Enable *Add mesh: extra objects* with *File* -> *User preferences* -> *Add-on*

- Generate linear to wave, with *Add* -> *Mesh* -> *math function* -> *XYZmath surface* and make sure you leave 'U wrap' blank:
  [image]
- Add a *mirror modifier* and enable the highlighted button:
  [image]
- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> tp enter *Edit mode* and move the waves from each other:
  [image]
- Add a *circle curve*:
  [image]
- Then select the wave and add a *curve modifier*
  [image]
- Scale the circle curve:
  [image]
- Scale everythong with -1 along the x-axis and rotate to obtain:
  [image]